# Finding duplicates when matching multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

@alon adler helped me out yesterday in creating some VBA code to remove duplicate rows from an Excel sheet, whereby the cell we are interrogating is of a certain colour, and has another cell in the same column with the same value.

I am now in need of adjusting the code, to match several columns in the row rather than just the one.
His code is below:

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_With_Color_Condition()

Dim toDel(), i As Long
Dim RNG As Range, Cell As Long

'Declare and set the worksheet where your data is stored
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Finding the last row in the Column 1
lastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set the range to the last row of data in the column
Set RNG = Range("a1:a" & lastRow) 'set your range here

'Iterate over the column, finding duplicates and store their address in an array
For Cell = 1 To RNG.Cells.Count
    If Application.CountIf(RNG, RNG(Cell)) > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve toDel(i)
        toDel(i) = RNG(Cell).Address
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
'Iterate over the array and remove duplicates with specific color index (in this example - remove the yellow ones)
For i = UBound(toDel) To LBound(toDel) Step -1
    If Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Value = ""
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I am really not clued up on VBA, and would like to know of an efficient way (the spreadsheet has about 45,000 rows to check against), to adjust the code to check that a range of columns all match another row.

For example, we want to ensure that for a row to be considered a duplicate, all cells in columns A to O have to match the value in the corresponding column on another row.

We then need to delete the row if it is NOT white. I determined that the delete command would be:

```
Rows(RowToDel).EntireRow.Delete
```

I believe I would then change :

```
If Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
```

To:

```
If Range(toDel(i)).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex <> 0 Then
```

If someone could assist with the matching multiple columns, I think I will be good to go.

Comment: My initial thought would be to capture your range in an array. Then start adding each row to a dictionary. Before you add it to the dictionary, check if dictionary already has that item. If it does, you know you have a duplicate. If not, add it to the dictionary. If I get time, I'll add the code in an answer. This is just to give you an idea of an approach you can take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. For the data as shown in the supporting image, row 2 would be deleted as it is a duplicate and it's interior is not like -4142 i.e. has a fill.

The code goes in a standard module.

You can un-comment the delete code to perform the delete

```
unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
```

and comment out the

```
Debug.Print unionRng.EntireRow.Address
```

which is currently showing you what would be deleted.

Yes, it is a little messy and could do with some re-factoring, for example, you could probably reduce the Evaluate(CONCATENATE...) string into something shorter maybe using Join.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_With_Color_Condition()

    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim currentRow As Long

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With targetSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row in column A and use this to determine the number of rows in range to work with

        Set RNG = .Range("A1:O" & lastRow)       'set your range here

        Dim toDel()
        toDel = RNG.Value2
        ReDim Preserve toDel(1 To UBound(toDel, 1), 1 To UBound(toDel, 2) + 2)

        Dim concatValuesDict As Scripting.Dictionary 'As Object
        Set concatValuesDict = New Scripting.Dictionary ' = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For currentRow = LBound(toDel, 1) To UBound(toDel, 1)

            Dim joinedString As String

            joinedString = Evaluate("CONCATENATE(""" & toDel(currentRow, 1) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 2) & toDel(currentRow, 3) & """,""" _
            & toDel(currentRow, 4) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 5) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 6) & """,""" & _
            toDel(currentRow, 7) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 8) & toDel(currentRow, 9) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 10) & """,""" & _
            toDel(currentRow, 11) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 12) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 13) & """,""" & toDel(currentRow, 14) & """,""" & _
           toDel(currentRow, 15) & """)") 'create a unique key for each row to determine duplicates by concatenating each column in the range

           toDel(currentRow, UBound(toDel, 2) - 1) = joinedString

           If Not concatValuesDict.Exists(joinedString) Then
               concatValuesDict.Add joinedString, False 'add these "keys" to a dictionary, and if "key" not already present then associated dictionary value =False
           Else
              concatValuesDict(joinedString) = True 'key seen before so duplicate so set value to True
           End If

        Next currentRow

        Dim unionRng As Range

        For currentRow = LBound(toDel, 1) To UBound(toDel, 1)

           toDel(currentRow, UBound(toDel, 2)) = concatValuesDict(toDel(currentRow, UBound(toDel, 2) - 1))

         If toDel(currentRow, UBound(toDel, 2)) And targetSheet.Rows(currentRow).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then  'Some fill is applied and the dictionary value for this row is True (i.e. is a duplicate)

             If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, targetSheet.Rows(currentRow).Cells(1, 1))   'add the key to a range for later deletion using union 
             Else
                Set unionRng = targetSheet.Rows(currentRow).Cells(1, 1)
             End If
         End If

        Next currentRow

        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then

            Debug.Print unionRng.EntireRow.Address
            ' unionRng.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Image of data:

[image: Data]

Example run:

[image: Running code]

Comment: Thanks for this. Sounds like it will do what I want. I am getting a compile error though "User-defined type not defined". Seems to be for "Dim concatValuesDict As Scripting.Dictionary"

Comment: Also, would it be possible to comment some of these lines so I can understand what the code is doing at each stage? Thank you

Comment: Have resolved this issue by enable a reference as per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128010/dim-as-dictionary-compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined I am now however running it now however, it does nothing and doesn't even give me a debug message.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have mentioned the reference. I will have a look and see what the problem might be but it suggested that unionRng is nothing ie no matching rows found so would need to inspect why the if condition is not being met for adding rows to unionRangd

Comment: I have added some notes for you

Comment: Did you have any thought on why this doesn't seem to do anything? Thanks

Comment: My sheet name is Sheet1, same as in the script, but when I click run with that line commented or uncommented, nothing happens. I expected the debug print to show me something, but it does not

Comment: No nothing printed. The cells are filled yellow, so should be triggering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167357/discussion-between-qharr-and-eds).

Comment: Sorry I was called away from my desk. the .Color is set to 65535 when I record it via a macro recorder

Comment: My issue was I was not putting the code into a module D'oh!

Comment: Huzzah!   If I had hair I would have been tearing it out.

Comment: Is there likely to be a limit to how many lines this macro can process? Running on a workbook of 45,000 Rows it doesn't work at all from what I can tell.

Comment: In theory not. Checking that many rows for conditional formatting etc might be slow. I would need to run some tests but off the top of my head there shouldn't be a problem. In that instance it might be faster to load information into an array and loop the array. I have a meeting in a moment but will get back to you.

Comment: Does the entire row need to be highlighted? I took the file you sent me, added 3 extra rows all of the letter "g", highlighted cells A to O on one of those rows, and when I ran the macro, only your highlighted row was deleted, mine was not. EDIT: yes that seems to be the case. Can it be tweaked to only look in cells A to O for highlighting, or possibly just ANY cell on that row being highlighted?

Comment: Yes it was looking for entire row. You can specify by adapting the And condition for example if looking for column A being highlighted in row  targetSheet.Rows(currentRow).Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142   This targetSheet.Rows(currentRow) was doing the whole row, cells(1,1) looks just at first cell in row i.e. column A of that row.