# Using VBA to searching for specific headers name, and grouping the data of these headers in several rename columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, header

In a big file that I am punctualy receiving, I am looking to reorganize data in a new sheet of the excel file.

I am thus looking for specific headers names and either renaming them and copying data or doing more complex operations.

In the simpler case, I am only renaming columns. I am looking for a column named "Spec A" and renaming it "Nabou"

For a more conplex case, I am creating a new column by concatenating columns. However, based on wether or not the information is present in other columns, I am adding a specific text, which can change in various cases. For example, I am concatenating a sevaral columns "nup", "nap", and adding "WAGA" for rows with values located below some specific headers, and adding "CIOCOLATO" for the rows with no values located in these same headers.

The two possible results being:

- nup_nap_WAGA_Snip (for the caeses when specific rows have values below)
- nup_nap_CIOCOLATO_Snip (for the cases when rows below specific headers have no values)

For the worst case, in this same file, I am creating new columns, by concatenating these columns, but I am also appending a specific number in some cases.
In oder to know the number that I am incrementing, I need to look on another exel file (another worksheet) to add a specific input in the increment, which should be increment based on specific condition.

For example I would have this result. The "003" is based on the inscpection of the other workbook, which will look on rows below a specific header for the term "Lettuce" and add "003" when "002" is found after "lettuce":

Lettuce003_SDS_FSGTEGT
Cake0049_SDEWF_TGEGT
Birthday004_FEGGE_GTEG

Here is the example files. For simplicity, I am not adding the second worksheet, in which I woulike to increment an number in the output file based on a comparaison of the a information in the source worksheet and this worksheet :

Here is the source file :

[image: Source file]

Here is the output file:

[image: Output file]

Here is my current result...with the macro, whih is far from what I am trying to do

[image]

Here is the code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Snouba()

    Const q = """"

' get source data table from sheet 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        ' check if data exists

        If .Rows.Count < 2 Or .Columns.Count < 2 Then
            MsgBox "No data table"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' retrieve headers name and column numbers dictionary
        Dim headers As Object
        Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim headCell
        For Each headCell In .Rows(1).Cells
            headers(headCell.Value) = headers.Count + 1
        Next

        ' check mandatory headers
        For Each headCell In Array("Nabou", "Wurp", "Scope 1", "Scope 2", "Scope 3”, "Scope 4", "NipandNup")
            If Not headers.Exists(headCell) Then
                MsgBox "Header '" & headCell & "' doesn't exists"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next

        Dim data

        ' retrieve table data
        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With

    ' process each row in table data
    Dim result As Object
    Set result = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)


     Select Case True
            Case _
                data(i, headers("NipandNup")) = "Nip"
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For

            Case _
                  result(result.Count) = "Nip"

            Case Else
                     result(result.Count) = "Nup"

               End Select








        Select Case True
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Nabou")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers(""Wurp")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("NipandNup")) = ""
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Scope 1")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Scope 2")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Scope 3")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Scope 4")) = ""
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        data(i, headers("Nabou")) & _
                        "_Alpha" & _
                        "_" & data(i, headers("Wurp")) & _
                        "_" & data(i, headers("NipandNup"))



           Case Else
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        data(i, headers("Nabou")) & _
                        "_Alphabet" & _
                        "_" & data(i, headers("Wurp")) & _
                        "_" & data(i, headers("NipandNup"))

        End Select

       Next

    ' output result data to sheet 2
    If result.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No result data for output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(result.Count).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.Items())
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

I manage to sucessfully rename columns with this, but it is not copying the columns in the second sheet, and evidently, not their content:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Changeheadername()

    Dim lastCol As Long, idCount As Long, nameCount As Long, headerRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    headerRow = 1       'row number with headers
    lastCol = Cells(headerRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column in header row
    idCount = 1
    nameCount = 1
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(headerRow, 1), Cells(headerRow, lastCol)) 'header range

    For Each cel In rng                     'loop through each cell in header
        If cel = "Wurp" Then             'check if header is "Wurp"
            cel = "Snouba"                    'rename 

        ElseIf cel = "Nabou" Then       'check if header is "Nabou"
            cel = "WAGD"                     'rename 

              ElseIf cel = "Scope 1" Then       'check if header is "Scope 1"
            cel = "I am an a wise rabbit"             

        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you by chance tried Power Query for this?

Comment: I tried, but there securities restrictions on power query and I might lack experience on power query as well. Would it make more sense to use power query ?

Comment: Could you clarify the layout of your data as it's not very clear from your question?

Comment: Hi, I tried adding details on data layout

Comment: How the source and expected results sheets look like? It's not clear what is the purpose of the function `ConCat`.

Comment: As you cn see in am also trying to rename colums and copy their content. I know that the column copying should look somewhat like this : `"Sub OneCell()
    Sheets("Sheet2").range("B1:B3").value = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1:A3").value` But in that case, my column would need to be fixed, because I am not looking for columns name. 
End Sub"

Comment: The "Scripting.Dictionary" is being used to store all the headers ? I am trying to either use this object, or to use range, in other to complete the macro and rename the headers and then copying these, but I am still struggling. Is the purpuse of Msg box to help in the debuging, in order to indicate for example, which columns is in the dictionnary but not found in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example showing how you can refer to columns by their header names while processing table data, even if columns located in different order:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Const q = """"
    ' get source data table from sheet 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        ' check if data exists
        If .Rows.Count < 2 Or .Columns.Count < 2 Then
            MsgBox "No data table"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' retrieve headers name and column numbers dictionary
        Dim headers As Object
        Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim headCell
        For Each headCell In .Rows(1).Cells
            headers(headCell.Value) = headers.Count + 1
        Next
        ' check mandatory headers
        For Each headCell In Array("Client", "Info Superman", "ID", "Spec 1", "Spec 2", "Spec a", "Spec b", "Info costumer type", "Info facility type")
            If Not headers.Exists(headCell) Then
                MsgBox "Header '" & headCell & "' doesn't exists"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        Dim data
        ' retrieve table data
        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    ' process each row in table data
    Dim result As Object
    Set result = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        Select Case True
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Client")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("Info Superman")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("ID")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("Info costumer type")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("Info facility type")) = ""
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Spec 1")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec 2")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec a")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec b")) = ""
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "Client " & data(i, headers("Client")) & _
                        q & q & "Superman " & data(i, headers("Info Superman")) & _
                        q & "Bravo" & _
                        q & "Info costumer type" & data(i, headers("Info costumer type")) & _
                        q & "Info facility type" & data(i, headers("Info facility type")) & _
                        q
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Spec a")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec b")) = ""
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "Client " & data(i, headers("Client")) & _
                        q & q & "Superman " & data(i, headers("Info Superman")) & _
                        q & "AlphaBravo" & _
                        q & "Info costumer type" & data(i, headers("Info costumer type")) & _
                        q & "Info facility type" & data(i, headers("Info facility type")) & _
                        q
            Case Else
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "Client " & data(i, headers("Client")) & _
                        q & q & "Superman " & data(i, headers("Info Superman")) & _
                        q & "AlphaAlphaBravo" & _
                        q & "Info costumer type" & data(i, headers("Info costumer type")) & _
                        q & "Info facility type" & data(i, headers("Info facility type")) & _
                        q
        End Select
    Next
    ' output result data to sheet 2
    If result.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No result data for output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(result.Count).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.Items())
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

The source data on the Sheet 1 I have tested is as follows:

[image: source]

And the output on the Sheet 2 is

[image: result]

That is just a boilerplate, you can easily change the code and adjust the logic for your exact layout.

Comment: Thank you ! This seems to be exactly this ! This is awesome !! I am currently trying to adapt the boiler plate template to my case. The only issue is that I am also trying to tailor the code, because a wide number (about 20) of the data field in the workbook need to be reused, with header changing names and data being kept below. For example I have a severla columns like "nip 111", which I need to keep. I also need to rename the types of columns like  "Spec 1" and "Spec a" in the file....I have added this but by doing so I have broken everything. I am going to investigate

Comment: When I try to apply this solution, I run into a compile error, "user defined type not defined": From my undertanding this caused by a library problem ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/858611/error-compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined-attempting-to-compil I have also been checking this answe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128010/dim-as-dictionary-compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined/46128994 but I do not have access to "references"

Comment: @TomasMichel I changed the code to late binding to avoid the error.

Comment: Thank you. I try using the solution provided, but I am always getting "does not exist" in a msg box. I do not understand why. I edited the question to provide a clearer picture of what I am struggling with.

Comment: @TomasMichel The message `"Header 'some header name' doesn't exists"` means as you can see that some header doesn't exists in the first row, and you are trying to use that missing header in your code. Please provide more info, share the exact code you are running, screenshot of the sheet with initial data, and full error message text.

Comment: Now it works ! The VBA completed without error ! But is not just copying the content of cells below the headers, the headers are also sistematically copied and repeated lines after lines after lines. How could the systemiatic header coping and "" be prevented ?

Comment: @TomasMichel Take a look for example at the line `q & "Client " & data(i, headers("Client")) & _`, here you can specify how to populate the rows: `q` adds the doublequote, `"Client "` adds the header name, and `data(i, headers("Client"))` is the content of the cell with header Client in the current row. Add or remove the parts you need.

Comment: Thank you this is really great ! But that I am trying to tailor it and adapt it in case which resemble this case, my second macro is not working, "dictionary" and "q" are already taken. I switched "q" with "m" and "m", and I called "dictionary" "dictionary2" but then I am told that it is not user defined

Comment: I now have a "miscmatch" error. When I use the debug, the given explanation is that I have a type mismatch for the "spec variable"...I do not understand why.

Comment: @TomasMichel Please show the exact line where the error occurs. I can't find `spec` variable in your code.

Comment: The indications provided greatly helped, but I am trying to adapt it and embed Else case an other else case for the third argument and this either breaks everything or copies the data in the second sheet but in tyo seperate lines instead of modyfing the concatenated column...

Comment: I updated the whole code in the original message. I am trying to add a condition, in order to modifiy what will be concatenated, depending on the third colum. Besides, I am wondering how to concatenate other columns with this same principels (looking for specific headers) without creating another module, and doing it in the same macro.

Comment: In the original column "NipandNup" there is either "Well, we have a small Nup" or "Oulalala we have a nip", and I was trying to reduce the lenght of the new concatenated columns by adding additional select case statement to the VBA code and reduce it to either "nup" or "nip" in the big concatenated column